# How does the openzeppelin library Bitmaps actually work?

Tags: openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

The openzeppelin provides a data structure library namely `BitMaps` which can be found here -
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/structs/BitMaps.sol

Can someone explain the logic of what exactly is going on in this library?
Like consider the function `get` -

```
    function get(BitMap storage bitmap, uint256 index) internal view returns (bool) {
        uint256 bucket = index >> 8;
        uint256 mask = 1 << (index & 0xff);
        return bitmap._data[bucket] & mask != 0;
    }
```

Here, why is `index>>8` done and what does `1 << (index & 0xff)` mean?

Could someone clarify this with an example by taking numbers and explaining a use case?

Also, what exactly does the struct Bitmap represents and what does it store?

```
    struct BitMap {
        mapping(uint256 => uint256) _data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The mapping is stored like this -

Buckets - 0,1,2,3,..... 2^256-1
Each bucket stores a 256 digit number which represents whether the corresponding bit is present or absent.

Bucket -> _______________ (256 digit boolean 1 or 0)
0 -> _________________ (256 digit boolean 1 or 0)
1 -> _________________ (256 digit boolean 1 or 0)
2 -> _________________ (256 digit boolean 1 or 0)
3 -> _________________ (256 digit boolean 1 or 0)
.
.
.
.
2^256-1 ->  _________________ (256 digit boolean 1 or 0)

Hence, to find the corresponding bucket an index belongs to, `index>>8` i.e `index/256` is done.
After finding the bucket, the corresponding position for that index inside the bucket is found!